# tfsdeleteproject.exe TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS cloud and I wish to delete a project. The web UI does not permit delete via an icon or button, so I am resorting to something like tfsdeleteproject.exe /collection:https://mycollection.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection myproject

I get response as follows:
tfsdeleteproject.exe TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access

I can't find options for supplying username/password - how to proceed?